# use center of view for alignment

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I'd like to use the center of a `View` to align it in another `View`, let's say, a `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout`.
I don't want to have it centered inside the `RelativeLayout` but rather offset from the bottom left corner.
At the moment I align the `TextView` `ParentLeft` and `ParentBottom` and use margins on left and bottom to move it away from those sides.
However, because my `TextView` is set to `wrap_content` in `width`, it "moves" around when the text inside and with it its `width` changes (since the borders of the `TextView` are used for the offsets).

I want the center of the `TextView` to stay on my offsetted position.
Is this possible in the `xml`, without having to write code that manages the offset or to use another layout?

That's the *unwanted* behaviour when the text changes: [Screen1](http://i.imgur.com/4AqdZz0)
The desirable behaviour: [Screen2](http://i.imgur.com/0Ahqk5w)
Note that the `center` of the `TextView` stays the same.

Comment: Could you post an image as an example of what you're trying to achieve? Or XML?

Comment: Added pictures to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple logic here. If you want to align a view with respect to the parent then for relative layout you can use align_parent wherein in linear use android:layout_gravity. Here in you case make textview as match_parent and set gravity to centre.